# Работа с сокетами в Objective C

Tags: сеть, сокеты, objective-c

Пишу программу, которая должна обращаться по сети к определенному адресу на заданный порт. После подключения программа должна отправить какое-либо сообщение в этот порт (например, просто цифру 0). В ответ программа должна получить строку с текущим временем в формате UNIX. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать такое взаимодействие по сети?

Comment: @maxprig, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

1) Можете реализовать это с помощью C сокетов. Информация легко находится поисковиком.

2) Можете использовать яблочный вариант [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html), [Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html).